# Display image from Database on WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I want to display images in a `DataGrid` from the database and I am using WPF

[[image: like this]]

I can retrieve image name as you can see in Image Column, but I am not able to display it.

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Path=Studentid}"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Picture" Width="50">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding Images/Students/ImageColumnNameInDatabase}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
 </DataGrid.Columns>
```

My c# code for filling the datagrid

```
conn = new SqlConnection(connstring);
conn.Open();
cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * From AddStudentTb", conn);
try
{
    DataGridView dv = new DataGridView();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    da.Fill(dt);
    datagridv.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
}
finally
{
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: where from image come ?

Comment: What you have tried? Show your code.

Comment: Please post your code to show your efforts. Looks like you are not binding the image in the right way.

Comment: I cant understand where to give relative  folders path to display images,, one more think I am retriving images in DataGrid but only those images which are saved like this C:\VSprojects\Images\play.png are displaying  ,but on the other hand i just saved name in database  like play.png  and thses images are in bin>Images>Students folder

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind image source in DataTemplate like,

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Image" Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="True">
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
           <Image Source="{Binding Image}" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Or you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/810906/wpf-image-bind-in-datagrid) question.

Comment: ok I understood but my images are saved in bin >Images     folder

Comment: @BilalMásInteligente : Please post your code. Then only I can understand the real issue.

Comment: SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
               
                da.Fill(dt);
                datagridv.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did
Add a datatemplate in your datagrid with image control like this

```
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="File Type" Width="*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Height="25" Width="50" Source="{Binding FileIcon}"  />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

As you can see my I am binding Image with a property named "FileIcon" that is used in class Version like this

```
            public class Version
            {
              public string FileIcon { get; set; }
            }
```

Now only this you have to do is bind provide a path to "FileIcon" and update ItemSource of DataGrid like this

```
            ObservableCollection<Version> items = new ObservableCollection<Version>();

            items.Add(new Version()
            {
                FileIcon = "Your Database Variable",
            });
            YourDataGrid.ItemsSource = null;
            YourDataGrid.ItemsSource = items;
```